# Symmetric 3-pire map

Tags: graph-theory, recreational-mathematics, coloring, polyhedra

Awhile ago, Martin Gardner introduced Scott Kim's symmetric 2-pire map.  There are 12 empires, each with two regions.  All twelve empires share a border.  This is a 2-pire solution for the [Empire Coloring Problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.2162).

[image: Scott Kim's 2-pire map]

In 3D, the [2-pire map](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/A2PireMap/) becomes a dodecahedron with each face split.

[image: Kim Dodecahedron]

For 3-pires, an 18 empire solution by Taylor is known.  It's not symmetric.

[image: Taylor 3-pire]

Is there a symmetric 18 empire 3-pire map?

Comment: The 2-pire map is clearly not symmetric in the sense of arc-transitive, because some of the regions have four neighbours and others have seven. That prompts the question of what exactly you want when you ask for a symmetric 3-pire map. Is a map with any non-trivial automorphism sufficient?

Comment: If you have access to an industrial SAT solver, it's fairly straightforward to encode for a fixed automorphism. One variable per potential edge; Bailleux-Boufkhad sum constraints to ensure exactly one border between each pair of empires; Hanani-Tutte planarity testing can be encoded in SAT; giving a SAT instance with on the order of 3.6 million variables and 14 million clauses before adding the equality constraints implied by the automorphism.

Comment: Progress report: I set up an instance with vertices $0,1,2$ forming one empire, $3,4,5$ forming a second, etc. and automorphism $(0,3,6,9,12,15) (18,21,24,27,30,33) (36,39,42,45,48,51) (7,10,13,16,19,22) (25,28,31,34,37,40) (43,46,49,52,1,4) (14,17,20,23,26,29) (32,35,38,41,44,47) (50,53,2,5,8,11)$ chosen as a generalisation of one of the automorphisms of the symmetric 2-pire map. cadical quickly reduced it to 66749 variables, but it's taken almost 10.3 days to reduce it to 66748 variables. I'll leave it running, but I think an inspired guess or some serious big iron is needed.

Comment: I don't have a UPS, so a 30-second power cut this morning aborted that SAT run without solution after just short of two months. I think I'll abandon the field for now.